# Turning off term frequency for all indexes and fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tf-idf

I want to eliminate term frequency from elastic search scoring while using tf-idf or BM25 - "texas texas" should produce the same score as "texas".  This can be done by using a mapping and setting the "index_options":"docs" as discussed in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192860/elasticsearch-disable-term-frequency-scoring).  However, that discussion does not indicate how to set "index_options":"docs" as a default applied to all indexes and all fields.  How would one go about this?  Also, is it possible to set this in the elasticsearch.yml or some other configuration file?  Please provide an example (solution should work for elasticsearch 2.3+),

Thanks